# .removeClass() not removing class. Possible specificity error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simultaneously add a class to a clicked link, while simultaneously removing that same class from the DOM. The part of the code that adds the class works, but it just makes the class appear again and again. I'm also curious about the efficacy of a javascript solution vs. a server-side solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $('#header a span').click(function(e) {
    var title = this.innerText; 
    //possible browser compatability from .text?
        $('selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        // Also prevent the link from being followed: 
    });
    });

<div id="header" class="ui-corner-all ui-buttonset">
         <a title="index" href="#" class="link" ><span>home</span></a>
         <a title="code" href="#" class="link" ><span>code</span></a>
         <a title="design" href="#" class="link" ><span>design</span></a>
         <a title="illustration" href="#"class="link" ><span>illustration</span></a>
         <a title="writing" href="#" class="link" ><span>writing</span></a>
         <a title="links" href="#" class="selected" ><span>links</span></a>
         <a title="about" href="#" class="selected"><span>about</span></a>
         </div>
```

Comment: `$('selected')` are you missing dot here?

Comment: `this.innerText` -> `$(this).text()`

Comment: Also no need to nest `$(document).ready()` and `$(function() {})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header a span').click(function(e) {
       var title = $(this).text();
       //possible browser compatability from .text?
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        // Also prevent the link from being followed: 
        return false;
    });
});
```

By the way, do you want your class `selected` on the `span` elements, or `a` elements, your JS indicates `span` but your html indicates `a`.

Comment: While you're at it, change a few other things that are mentioned in the question comments...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('selected').removeClass('selected');
```

should be

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs (.) Before it I think.

Comment: It's not worth answering questions if you just "think" that you know the answer.